# Pandas join index with value in column and ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
targets = {'index':[3, 4, 5],
        'sequence_id':[140366A0464161, 140366A0464178, 140366A0464189],
        'target': [0, 1, 0]}


data = {'sequence_id':[140366A0464161, 140366A0464161, 140366A0464161, 140366A0464178, 140366A0464178, 140366A0464178, 140366A0464178, 140366A0464178],
        'feature_1' : ['true', 'true', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'false']}
```

I'm wanting to create another dataframe where the `index` and `sequence_id` columns from `targets` corresponds to the index of the `sequence_id` in `data`.

By this I mean, the third index of `140366A0464161` would be `false` and a target of `0`, for example. The index might not always be the last instance for the each `sequence_id`. There is also more features in data than `features_1`.

My expected output would be:

```
   index     sequence_id  feature_1 target
0      3  140366A0464161    false     0
1      4  140366A0464178    false     0
2      5  140366A0464189    true      0
```

In terms of what I've tried: I've attempted a join based on the `sequence_id` but realise that it's much more than that as the index isn't the true in `data`, so this has me stumped!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
t = pd.DataFrame(targets)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#convert column to boolean
df['feature_1'] = df['feature_1'].map({'true':True, 'false':False})

#merge by index column with left join and replace missing values by `False`
df = (t.merge(df.reset_index(), on=['index','sequence_id'], how='left')
       .fillna({'feature_1':False}))

print (df)
   index     sequence_id  target  feature_1
0      3  140366A0464161       0      False
1      4  140366A0464178       1       True
2      5  140366A0464189       0      False
```

**Detail**:

```
print (t.merge(df.reset_index(), on=['index','sequence_id'], how='left'))
   index     sequence_id  target feature_1
0      3  140366A0464161       0       NaN
1      4  140366A0464178       1      True
2      5  140366A0464189       0       NaN
```

Comment: This attaches the wrong target to each row because you've assigned target = 0. The target should come from the target frame.

Comment: Also, there might be more features than just features_1. Should've clarified :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want to take last value for each sequence_id, because you have a several identical sequence_id in your 'data' dataframe (If you give additional information about desired join-logic, may be it will be another solution).

So the first step - convert it in appropriate format:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(targets).set_index('index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index('sequence_id')

conv_df = df2.groupby('sequence_id').nth([-1]) 

Out[80]: 
               feature_1
sequence_id             
140366A0464161     false
140366A0464178     false
```

so then just megre it:

```
df1.merge(conv_df, left_on = 'sequence_id', right_index = True)

Out[83]: 
          sequence_id  target feature_1
index                                  
3      140366A0464161       0     false
4      140366A0464178       1     false
```

Comment: The index might not always be the last instance for the each sequence_id. I'll edit the post to describe that.